# words into numbers scrape

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I scrape a webpage it returns this: `42,834.56`

Apparently, it extracts it as a word (because when I try to sum it whit the other ones retrieve in excel it doesn't work). How can I convert it into a number?

I'm copying from the cmd:

Here is an error when I write it with `int()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\py4e\callao.py", line 337, in <module>
    print(int(peso))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '42,834.56\xa0'
```

Here is an error when I write it with `float()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\py4e\callao.py", line 337, in <module>
    print(float(peso))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '42,834.56\xa0'
```

Comment: your output returns `42,834.56` as a `string`??

Comment: yes, when I copy and paste it in excel it doesn't sum with the other ones (I copy the other ones from the cmd as well)

Comment: you can convert your output to `float` or `int` as per your need

Comment: I tried that but it retrieves an error

Comment: so please edit your post and put code and with error so it will be easy to understand!

Comment: here you go, I edit it

Comment: Did you read the error message? Seems the the problem is extra characters. So you're not scraping it out right.

Comment: yes you need to remove first `\xa0`

Comment: But when I only write print(peso) it only retrieves 42,834.56

Comment: Your string ends with \xa0, that's not a digit, the other thing is the comma, the conversion may fail on these characters so you can replace them with nothing to strip them

Comment: please share the whole code for better clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to remove ',' from the number. Try this:

```
float("".join(peso.split(',')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the scraped value in a variable and convert to float in python. Here's the function:

```
def convert_to_float(peso):
    return float(peso.replace(',',''))
```

And here's the call to the function:

```
peso = '42,834.56'
convert_to_float(peso)
```

Output:

```
42834.56
```

Now you can sum it with others.

**Edit -**

It seems you have scraped \xa0 also along with the string. So to handle that:

```
def convert_to_float(peso):
    peso = peso.split("\\")[0]
    return float(peso.replace(',',''))

peso = '42,834.56\xa0'
convert_to_float(peso)
```

Output will be same as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "42,834.56"
b = float(a.replace(",",""))
print(type(b))

# output: <class 'float'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

- Strip off the `\xa0` character.
- Remove the `,` from the string
- Convert it to float.

```
s = '42,834.56\xa0'
s = s.strip()
print(float(s.replace(',','')))
```